# How to redirect the output of a c program to a file?

Tags: c

I am trying to redirect the output of a c program to file, even when it generates some errors because of problems with the input data. I can send the output but the error messages to a file.

Does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and a correct answer is very dependent on your environment.  Voting to move to superuser.com.

Comment: Why this isn't a programming related question?? Outputs can be redirected from C code!

Comment: It should go back to StackOverflow. The answer with most upvotes is programming related. Nothing to do with batch.

Comment: I seriously doubt the question would sound anything like this if the OP was wanting to do the redirection from inside the program.  Either you'd just write to the file directly (if you have control over the I/O calls), or you'd be asking how to force a third-party library (not program) to direct its output to a file.  This question is begging for a shell-based solution, and every single answer proposed over at SO assumed that, even though shell invocation is off-topic there.

Comment: please read it: "redirect the output of a c program to file". does it smell like redirection from outside a program? yes, writing directly to file is possible. forcing third party library to redirect to a file is possible. yet, redirecting outputs to file is also possible from within the program. i believe the OP asked how to do that.

Answer (score 8):

From within C source code, you can redirect outputs using [`freopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen):

General outputs:

```
freopen("myfile.txt", "w", stdout);
```

Errors:

```
freopen("myfile_err.txt", "w", stderr);
```

Answer (score 3):

(This answer applies to bash shell, and similar flavors. You didn't specify your environment and this sort of question needs that detail.)

I assume you know about basic redirection with ">".  To also capture STDERR in addition to STDOUT, use the following syntax:

```
command > file-name 2>&1
```

For some more background on standard streams and numbers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29

Comment: I believe that you have to do those in the other order, they way you have it would put the stdout of command into file-name, and the stderr of command into stdout of the pipeline.  Also Aldo didn't say he is using bash, in fact there's nothing at all in the question to suggest that.

Comment: The order is correct but you're right about the bash assumption.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you mean and what platform you are using.  Very often you can accomplish this from the command line, which has been covered in another answer.  If you use this method to accomplish this you should be aware that `FILE * stderr` is typically written immediately (unbuffered) while `FILE * stdout` may be buffered (usually line buffered) so you could end up with some of your error messages appearing to have been printed earlier than some other messages, but actually the other messages are just being printed late.

From within a C program you can also do something similar within the stdio system using `freopen`, which will effect the `FILE *`, so you could make `fprintf(stderr, "fungus");` print to something besides what stderr normally would print to.

But if you want to know how to make a program redirect the actual file descriptors under a unix like system you need to learn about the `dup` and `dup2` system calls.  They allow you to duplicate a file descriptor.

```
int fd = open("some_file", O_WRONLY);
dup2(2,fd);
close(fd);
```

This code will make "some_file" the new stderr at the OS level.  The dup2 call will close and replace file descriptor 2 (stderr, which is usually used by `FILE * stderr` but not necessarily if you call `freopen(x,y,stderr)` since that may make `FILE *stderr` use a different file descriptor).

This is how shell programs redirect input and output of programs.  The open all of the files that the new program will need, `fork`, then the child uses `dup2` to set up the files descriptors for the new program, then it closes any files that the new program won't need (usually just leaving 0, 1, and 2 open), and then uses one of the exec functions to become the program that the shell was told to run.  (some of this isn't entirely accurate because some shells may rely on close on exe flags)

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple linux command you can save the output into the file. here is a simple linux terminal command.

```
ls > file.txt
```

The output of this command will be stored into the file. 
**same as you can store the output of the program like this suppose, object file name is a, run the following command to save output in a file:**

```
./a > file.txt
```